# An efficient way to perform an all reduction in MPI of a value based on another variable?

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, mpi, reduction

As an example, lets say I have

```
int a = ...;
int b = ...;
int c;
```

where `a` is the result of some complex local calculation and `b` is some metric for the quality of `a`.

I'd like to send the best value of `a` to every process and store it in `c` where best is defined by having the largest value of `b`.

I guess I'm just wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this than doing an `allgather` on `a` and `b` and then searching through the resulting arrays.

The actual code involves sending and comparing several hundred values on upto several hundred/thousand processes, so any efficiency gains would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess I'm just wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing
> this than doing an allgather on a and b and then searching through the
> resulting arrays.

This can be achieved with **only a single** [MPI_AllReduce](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Allreduce.html).

I will present two approaches, a simpler one (suitable for your use case); and a more generic one, for more complex use-cases. The latter will also be useful to show case MPI functionality such as custom MPI Datatypes and custom MPI reduction operators.

**Approach 1**

To represent

```
int a = ...;
int b = ...;
```

you could use the following struct:

```
typedef struct MyStruct {
    int b;
    int a;
} S;
```

then you can use the MPI Datatype [MPI_2INT](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mpi_2int) and the MPI operator [MAXLOC](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-1.1/node79.htm)

> The operator MPI_MINLOC is used to compute a global minimum and also
> an index attached to the minimum value. **MPI_MAXLOC similarly computes
> a global maximum and index. **One application of these is to compute a
> global minimum (maximum) and the rank of the process containing this
> value.**

In your case, instead of the `rank` we will be using the value of 'a'. Hence, the `MPI_AllReduce` call:

```
 S  local, global;
 ...
 MPI_Allreduce(&local, &global, 1, MPI_2INT, MPI_MAXLOC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The complete code would look like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

typedef struct MyStruct {
    int b;
    int a;
} S;


int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL); // Initialize the MPI environment
    int world_rank; 
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_size);
    
    // Some fake data
    S local, global;
    local.a = world_rank;
    local.b = world_size - world_rank;

    MPI_Allreduce(&local, &global, 1, MPI_2INT, MPI_MAXLOC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
          
    if(world_rank == 0){
      printf("%d %d\n", global.b, global.a);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
 }
```

**Second Approach**

The `MPI_MAXLOC` only works for a certain number of [predefined datatypes](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mpi_2int). Nonetheless, for the remaining cases you can use the following approach **(based on this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712837/is-mpi-allreduce-on-a-structure-with-fields-of-the-same-type-portable))**:

1. Create a `struct` that will contain the values `a` and `b`;
2. Create a customize `MPI_Datatype` representing the 1. `struct` to be *sent* across processes;
3. Use `MPI_AllReduce`:

> int MPI_Allreduce(const void *sendbuf, void *recvbuf, int count,
> MPI_Datatype datatype, MPI_Op op, MPI_Comm comm)
>
> Combines values from all processes and distributes the result back to
> all processes

4. Use the operation `MAX`;

> I'd like to send the best value of 'a' to every process and store it in
> 'c' where best is defined by having the largest value of 'b'.

5. Then you have to *tell* MPI to only consider the element `b` of the struct. Hence, you need to create a custom `MPI_Op` max operation.

**Coding the approach**

So let us break step-by-step the aforementioned implementation:

First define the `struct`:

```
typedef struct MyStruct {
    double a, b;
} S;
```

Second create the customize `MPI_Datatype`:

```
void defineStruct(MPI_Datatype *tstype) {
    const int count = 2;
    int          blocklens[count];
    MPI_Datatype types[count];
    MPI_Aint     disps[count];

    for (int i=0; i < count; i++){
        types[i] = MPI_DOUBLE;
        blocklens[i] = 1;
    }
    disps[0] = offsetof(S,a);
    disps[1] = offsetof(S,b);

    MPI_Type_create_struct(count, blocklens, disps, types, tstype);
    MPI_Type_commit(tstype);
}
```

**Very Important**
Note that since we are using a `struct` you have to be careful with the fact that ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712837/is-mpi-allreduce-on-a-structure-with-fields-of-the-same-type-portable))

> the C standard allows arbitrary padding between the fields.

So reducing a `struct` with two `double`s is **NOT** the same as reducing an array with two `double`s.

In the *main* you have to do:

```
MPI_Datatype structtype;
defineStruct(&structtype);
```

Third create the custom max operation:

```
void max_struct(void *in, void *inout, int *len, MPI_Datatype *type){
    S *invals    = in;
    S *inoutvals = inout;
    for (int i=0; i < *len; i++)
        inoutvals[i].b  = (inoutvals[i].b > invals[i].b) ? inoutvals[i].b  : invals[i].b;
}
```

in the *main* do:

```
MPI_Op       maxstruct;
MPI_Op_create(max_struct, 1, &maxstruct);
```

Finally, call the `MPI_AllReduce`:

```
S local, global;
...
MPI_Allreduce(&local, &global, 1, structtype, maxstruct, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The entire code put together:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

typedef struct MyStruct {
    double a, b;
} S;

void max_struct(void *in, void *inout, int *len, MPI_Datatype *type){
    S *invals    = in;
    S *inoutvals = inout;
    for (int i=0; i<*len; i++)
        inoutvals[i].b  = (inoutvals[i].b > invals[i].b) ? inoutvals[i].b  : invals[i].b;
}

void defineStruct(MPI_Datatype *tstype) {
    const int count = 2;
    int          blocklens[count];
    MPI_Datatype types[count];
    MPI_Aint     disps[count];

    for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
        types[i] = MPI_DOUBLE;
        blocklens[i] = 1;
    }
    disps[0] = offsetof(S,a);
    disps[1] = offsetof(S,b);

    MPI_Type_create_struct(count, blocklens, disps, types, tstype);
    MPI_Type_commit(tstype);
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL); // Initialize the MPI environment
    int world_rank; 
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_size);
    MPI_Datatype structtype;
    MPI_Op       maxstruct;
    S  local, global;

    defineStruct(&structtype);
    MPI_Op_create(max_struct, 1, &maxstruct);

    // Just some random values
    local.a = world_rank;
    local.b = world_size - world_rank;

    MPI_Allreduce(&local, &global, 1, structtype, maxstruct, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
          
    if(world_rank == 0){
      double c = global.a;
      printf("%f %f\n", global.b, c);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome. I didn't realize it was possible to define custom datatypes like this! It will make a lot if stuff easier in the future :D

Answer (score 2):

You can pair the value of `b` with the rank of the process to find the rank that contains the maximum value of `b`. The `MPI_DOUBLE_INT` type is very useful for this purpose. You can then broadcast `a` from this rank in order to have the value at each process.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int my_rank;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    // Create random a and b on each rank.
    srand(123 + my_rank);
    double a = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
    double b = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;

    struct
    {
        double value;
        int rank;
    } s_in, s_out;

    s_in.value = b;
    s_in.rank = my_rank;

    printf("before: %d, %f, %f\n", my_rank, a, b);

    // Find the maximum value of b and the corresponding rank.
    MPI_Allreduce(&s_in, &s_out, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_INT, MPI_MAXLOC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    b = s_out.value;

    // Broadcast from the rank with the maximum value.
    MPI_Bcast(&a, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, s_out.rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("after: %d, %f, %f\n", my_rank, a, b);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Or so mply use `a` instead of the rank, and skip the broadcast.

Comment: Like in the first part of the other answer, for example. Note that no one forces you to set the second member of the struct to the rank. It could be anything.

Comment: @HristoIliev, ah MAXLOC returns the value of the second argument where the first has its max? In that case I misunderstood its meaning. Great :).

Comment: It returns the lowest value of the index field that corresponds to the min/max value. Using the rank as the index allows you to find out which is the lowest rank that holds the min/max value, but that's just one use case.

Comment: @dreamcrash, I did not update my answer, I still do the double communication where one could suffice.

Comment: @Chiel Feel free to update similar to the stuff that I have done I would not mind.

Comment: @Chiel Sorry I actually meant why didn't you update